# How to get a prop from another parent-prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to set a value of prop named "dates:" which is situated in another prop-parent named "attributes:". I cant find dates: because its in array of prop attributes: and I cant set date's value in method created() because of that. How can I get access to prop "dates:" and change its value?

```
export default {
    name: "Vacations",
    data() {
        return {
            vacantDays: '5',
            isActive: false,
            vacDates: null,
            occupiedDays: [new Date("03 January 2019")],
            attr:
                [
                {
                    highlight: {
                        backgroundColor: '#ff8080',     // Red background
                        borderColor: '#ff6666',
                        borderWidth: '2px',
                        borderStyle: 'solid',
                    },
                    contentStyle: {
                        color: 'white',                 // White text
                    },
                    dates: [5],
                },
                ]
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$acl.change(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        let name = localStorage.getItem('username');
        instance.get("/calendar/occupied",{
            params: {
                name: name
            }
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            let datesArray = res.data.map(dateString => new Date(dateString));
            console.log(datesArray);
            //this.attr.dates=datesArray;
            console.log(this.attr.get(dates));
        }).catch(err=> {
            console.log(err);
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: var that = this; in the created function and then inside your http call response handler use that.attr[0].dates

Comment: Why do you keep it in array in first place if it's just one object? It can be accessed by using `this.attr[0].dates` but what would you do if there is more than one object?